# Problems with python alarm at specified hours

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, alarm

I'm trying to make a "alarm" for my classes and it does that when a certain hour comes it does something (in this case it just prints, and i will change that when the code works) and it repeats until next alarm.The problem here is that when i run the code 1 min before it prints `it's time` , and then it reaches the alarm time and it still prints the same and not `not yet`.

I want the code to keep running after the if statements. Here's the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
now = datetime.now()

current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
today = now.strftime("%A")

cn = "22:14"
ing ="21:23"

day = {0:"Monday", 1:"Tuesday", 2:"Wednesday"
, 3:"Thursday", 4:"Friday", 5:"Saturday", 6:"Sunday"}


def mday():
 if (today == day[0]) and (current_time == cn):
  print("its time")
  time.sleep(1)
  mday()
 else:
  print("not yet")
  time.sleep(1)
  mday()
mday()
```

Comment: From the looks of it, It appears to be as you're calling `mday()` even after the time is reached. omitting the line in the if condition should rectify the issue.

Comment: Your `current_time` does not change while you are in recursion. So the outcome of your `if` is predefined and would not vary.

Comment: It checks current_time == cn, but current_time does not change as PM 77-1 posted, change that to now.strftime("%H:%M") == cn, or declare a varible inside your function that re-assigns current_time to now.strftime("%H:%M").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem with your code (why it does not work at all), is that you do not update the values of the `today` and `current_time` variables. That you sleep for one second in each call to `mday()` does not affect these variables. You need to update them right at the entry to `mday`.

The second problem is that you have infinite recursion here. Infinite *loops* run forever, which is what you want, I guess. Infinite recursion, on the other hand, simply uses up the stack, and crashes you application. You would need to convert the recursive function `mday` to one with an infinite loop. To do that, place all the `if` statement from inside `mday` inside a forever loop: (`while True:`), and 
also remove the two recursive calls from the end of the branches. You can also take the `sleep` calls out of the `if` - remove one of them, and place the other after the the content of the `else` block:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

cn = "22:14"
ing ="21:23"

day = {
  0:"Monday",
  1:"Tuesday",
  2:"Wednesday",
  3:"Thursday",
  4:"Friday",
  5:"Saturday",
  6:"Sunday"
}

def mday():
  while True:
    # Update current time values
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
    today = now.strftime("%A")
    # Print alarm/no-alarm message
    if (today == day[0]) and (current_time == cn):
      print("its time")
    else:
      print("not yet")
    time.sleep(1)

mday()
```

There are many ways this code can be optimized, but the above will produce roughly the result you want.

Comment: Upvote for differentiating loops and recursion.  Nice one.

Comment: How do i do that? im kinda new to python